# How to enable auto-align in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I want to auto-align my code to make it easier to read, in a click. I am working on Sublime Text 3 and want to know about a method through which I can enable auto-indent of the code in just a click.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend the `AlignTab` extension: https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab (with Demo)

Answer (score 3):

By using the https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab package, you can activate the `Table Mode` which constantly aligns the code for you, until you run the command `Exit Table Mode`, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
{"keys": ["f12"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the title bar, go to Preferences > Key Bindings, then add this binding to "Key Bindings - User" file.

```
{"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

Now whenever you want to auto-align your code, just highlight the desired code and press `alt+shift+f`

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/7yxpdw/auto-indenting-on-sublime-text-3

---

**Note:** This was the original answer from the OP @Utkarsh (with score 18) that OP deleted and edited into the question.